# change compile version of existing jar file in java

Tags: java, jar, java-5

I have bccapi-1.2.0.jar file which i want to run on linux server but it could not run because of its compile version.

Compile version of jar file is jdk1.7 which i downloaded from URL: http://www.antepedia.com/detail/p/bccapi.html

Server's jdk is jdk1.5. So how can i recompile existing jar with jdk1.5 environment.
When i am trying to run that it give error like that

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class
>   file (unable to load class com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2858)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
>     com.elitecore.activation.utilities.CryptUtilities.validateScryptPassword(CryptUtilities.java:135)
>     inventory.Application.CUsers.getUserBeanByNameandPassword(CUsers.java:131)
>     inventory.modes.ChkLogin.process(ChkLogin.java:55)
>     inventory.servlet.UserServlet.doPost(UserServlet.java:62)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)

This error occured when i am executing jar file on server.

[image: This error occured when i am executing jar file on server]

Comment: Is there no possibility of updating your server to have a JRE which was released in the last decade?

Comment: If the jar you downloaded has been compiled with jdk1.7, it probably uses specific features that don't exist within jdk1.5. I'm afraid you have to upgrade the jre on your server to 1.7

Comment: thanks for response, but it won't be possible right now because whole project and its dependences are there. so if i will do then many issue may occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found a required java file(com.lambdaworks,SCrypUtils.java) source code from https://github.com/wg/scrypt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lambdaworks/crypto/SCryptUtil.java

So I opened in Eclipse and just change compile version to java 1.5 like right click on project -> properties -> java compiler -> change to 1.5

Then exported this project with jar. so i happy that i didn't require to change server configuration and run project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your project's environment into jdk 1.7 so that you can use your jar file.

Comment: Yes that's i know. but i won't be able to do because of more than one projects are there on server and which are running with jdk1.5. So i afraid to do this solution.

Comment: So we can not be able to recompile existing jar file with different version of java.?

Comment: @vimalsuthar sorry for my mistake, I mean you could set up the environment of your project into jdk1.7 and should be able to run on server. For me, I have multiple projects running both on jdk 1.7 and 1.5 and they still are able to run on the same server.

Comment: It's fine @chit Khine but i am not able to convert whole project with jdk1.5 as i said before so i need to recompile jar with compatible with jdk1.5 and also i do not require for change in jar file just i need to recompile in jdk1.5 only.

Comment: if u have enough confidence, you can change your server's environment to 1.7 but as u worry it can cause you problems. I have no idea on how u can run the jar which requires 1.7 with 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Download the sources from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/bccapi/source-archive.zip
And try to compile the library for/with Java 5, maybe you will have to apply some changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i require lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtis.java but there is not present in which you have given source code. and i do not require change in existing code just i need to recompile jar file or code with jdk1.5.

Comment: Java 1.5 and 1.7 have a slightly different bytecode and some things have changed like the override annotation, switch on strings, diamond, try with resources etc.

Try this:
- decompile your jar e.g. via cfr http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/
- Create a new project
- set your project as Java 5 project
- paste the decompiled code
- fix all the errors and warnings
- export your own library.

I am not sure about the license in this case.